# How can I add an "@" symbol in Angular4 "ngFor"?

Tags: json, angular

Im not able to use the @ symbol in Angular 4  *ngFor, it throws Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [@]

I tried to use **, '', "" and `` , none seems to work, I already made a XML to JSON conversion (that is why the array has the @ symbols).

This is my Angular code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of dataResumen">
 <td class="border" text-center>{{data.@INDICATOR}}</td>
</tr>
```

and the json:

```
"data": [
        {
            "@DATA_DOMAIN": "CGO",
            "@REF_AREA": "PA",
            "@INDICATOR": "PAN_CGO_GCRG_XDC",
            "@COUNTERPART_AREA": "_Z",
            "@FREQ": "Q",
            "@UNIT_MULT": "6",
            "Obs": [
                {
                    "@TIME_PERIOD": "2018-Q4",
                    "@OBS_VALUE": "3672.0896000000002"
                }
            ]
        },
]
```

Comment: Does `data["@INDICATOR"]` work?

Comment: Hi, no it does not @R.Richards

Comment: hi @dota2pro no it doesn't, it was a creative workaround but no, same error "Unexpected character [@] "

Comment: I tested `data["@INDICATOR"]` in Angular 7 and it's working!

Comment: Hi @Eiman , for some reason in Angular4 it only prints the string "data["@INDICATOR"]"  maybe is because the "{{ }}"  keys are a must ?

Comment: Yes, @R.Richards meant `{{ data["@INDICATOR"] }}`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan wow it worked !!  that's weird, for some reason it doesn't work if I don't leave blank space, thank you R.Richards and the rest !!!! you are the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered by @R.Richards and the rest of the team comments, did it with `{{ data["@INDICATOR"] }}`  for some reason In order to work I have to leave an blank space between the  curly braces {{*blankspace*data["@INDICATOR"]*blankspace*}}.